# Load earlier text messages

Tags: iphone

I just got a new iPhone 6plus my text messages are only saving one screen full. I have no "load earlier messages" prompt. how do I view a message from a week ago?

Comment: Please add more details to your question: when did you get your new iPhone? When you say: "my text messages are only saving one screen full" do you mean when new messages arrive, old messages disappear? Do you have iMessage on? iOS version? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Define "just got" - as in today? Or as before a week ago? It sounds like your new device was not restored from a backup and was instead set up as new, in which case your previous text messages are not available.